# Error trying to compile typescript `ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope`

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

I am trying to get a typescript project up and running, but keep running into this error...
`ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope`. And if I remove "type":"module" from my package.json I get this error `code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM`. I am a little lost on how to fix this issue.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.48.0",
    "prettier": "3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.6.0"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.6.0",
    "yarn": "3.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cli-table3": "^0.6.3",
    "common-js": "^0.3.8",
    "execa": "^8.0.1",
    "p-queue": "^7.4.0",
    "pretty-bytes": "^6.1.1",
    "ts-dedent": "^2.2.0",
    "yargs": "^17.7.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "lib": ["es2015"]
    }
  }
```

I tried adding and removing "type":"module" from package.json and also tried removing       "esModuleInterop": true, these all take me to different errors. Eventually adding both of these leads to the error above.

Comment: You cannot use `module.exports` or `exports` when using esm. You need to use `export`.